# Proper way to execute block of code when loop finishes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I often run into a situation in which I want to execute a block of code within a loop when a condition is met and also when the loop finishes. I have usually gotten around this with indexing/enumerations or copy and pasting. I'm wondering if there is a more built in way to deal with this, kind of like a `do while` loop (which I do know Python does not have). In the example below I want to call a function everytime the condition fails and when we have finished iterating through the list.

```
y = []
for num in x:
    if condition:
        y.append(num)
    else:
        function_call(y)
        y = []
function_call(y)
```

Comment: I do not think so this is a bad approach or should be called a workaround, that's a genuine way to handle this type of condition. It is like creating your own do-while.

Comment: I wouldn't disagree when the code is as simple as simple as this. However, it feels very cumbersome to me if the code I need to duplicate is any longer than one or two lines. Then again, if it's getting too long then maybe I should be creating a function anyway...

Answer (score 1):

First, I would catch the case where the assertion fails at the beginning, then if the condition is valid, process:

```
y = []
for num in x:
    if not condition:
        function_call(y)
        y = []
        continue
    y.append(num)

function_call(y)
```

This way, the fallback is explicit.

Then, if you want to avoid the final block you could imagine a workaround like that, but it has to be done with caution because it does'nt help to to keep the code readable:

```
y = []
for num in x + [None]:    # I assume `x` is a list?
    if not condition or num is None:   
        function_call(y)
        y = []
        continue
    y.append(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

You solve this the same way you did, and if the code that `function_call` symbolises is long then you make it a function like so:

**Before:**

```
y = []
for num in x:
    if condition:
        y.append(num)
    else:
        function_call_1(y)
        function_call_2(y)
        function_call_3(y)
        function_call_4(y)
        function_call_5(y)
        y = []
function_call_1(y)
function_call_2(y)
function_call_3(y)
function_call_4(y)
function_call_5(y)
```

**After:**

```
def function_call(arg):
    function_call_1(arg)
    function_call_2(arg)
    function_call_3(arg)
    function_call_4(arg)
    function_call_5(arg)

y = []
for num in x:
    if condition:
        y.append(num)
    else:
        function_call(y)
        y = []
function_call(y)
```